# sql compact edition export or import to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I've got simple table in SQLCE 4.0 that i want export to XML file
and later import back after modify the XML.

can i use some query: select * from mytable FOR XML

What possibilities do I have?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why would you not just want to modify the table?

Comment: its complicate to explain.